# PHP foreach array_combine

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```js
// choices array
    $choices = [];
    $choices[1] = $_POST['choice1'];
    $choices[2] = $_POST['choice2'];
    $choices[3] = $_POST['choice3'];
 
 $titlu = [];
 $titlu[1] = $_POST['titlu1'];
    $titlu[2] = $_POST['titlu2'];
    $titlu[3] = $_POST['titlu3'];
    
    if($insert_row){

        foreach(array_combine($choices, $titlu) as $choice => $titlu)
  {
           if($choice != ''){
               if($correct_choice == $choice) {
                   $is_correct = 1;
               } else {
                   $is_correct = 0;
               }
               $query = "INSERT INTO `choices`(question_number, is_correct, choice, titlu)VALUES('$question_number', '$is_correct', '$choice', '$titlu')";

               $insert_row = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

               if($insert_row) {
                   continue;
               } else {
                   die('Error : ('.$mysqli->errno.') ' . $mysqli->error);
               }
           } 
        }
        $msg = "Questions has been added";
    }
}
```

My database tables are:

```js
"Choices" which contain:

---------------------------------------------------
id | question_number | is_correct | choice | titlu |
---------------------------------------------------
```

My old code was without "titlu" row, i added it, and i used "aray_combine" for that .
Everything is working fine, rows are filled with info, but "is_correct" row don't work anymore. It show only "0" on all rows, even i select to show "1" .
Hope you understand me! I'm begginer, but i'm ready to learn.
Thank you!

Comment: What is value of $correct_choice variable? Can you also post your HTML here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where are you getting your `correct_choice` value from.. but i did a quick test and it's working as expected.

```
$choices = [];
$choices[1] = 'bar';
$choices[2] = 'foo';
$choices[3] = 'elo';

$correct_choice = 'foo'; //added


$titlu = [];
$titlu[1] =  'llo';
$titlu[2] ='plo';
$titlu[3] = 'clo';


    foreach(array_combine($choices, $titlu) as $choice => $titlu)
    {
       if($choice != ''){
           if($correct_choice == $choice) {
               $is_correct = 1;
           } else {
               $is_correct = 0;
           }
           $query = "INSERT INTO `choices`(question_number, is_correct, choice, titlu)VALUES('1', '$is_correct', '$choice', '$titlu')";

           echo $query . "<br/>";
       } 
    }
    $msg = "Questions has been added";
```

output is

```
INSERT INTO `choices`(question_number, is_correct, choice, titlu)VALUES('1', '0', 'bar', 'llo')
INSERT INTO `choices`(question_number, is_correct, choice, titlu)VALUES('1', '1', 'foo', 'plo')
INSERT INTO `choices`(question_number, is_correct, choice, titlu)VALUES('1', '0', 'elo', 'clo')
```

may be there is something wrong with the way your `correct_choice`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML form:

```html
<form method="post" action="add.php">
          <p>
   <label>Question Number</label>
   <input type="number" value="<?php echo $next; ?>" name="question_number" />
     </p>
          <p>
   <label>Question</label>
   <input type="text" name="question_text" />
     </p>
          <p>
   <label>Choice #1: </label>
   <input type="text" name="choice1" />
     </p>
          <p>
   <label>Choice #2: </label>
   <input type="text" name="choice2" />
     </p>
          <p>
   <label>Choice #3: </label>
   <input type="text" name="choice3" />
     </p>
     <p>
   <label>TITLU #1: </label>
   <input type="text" name="titlu1" />
     </p>
     <p>
   <label>TITLU #2: </label>
   <input type="text" name="titlu2" />
     </p>
     <p>
   <label>TITLU #3: </label>
   <input type="text" name="titlu3" />
     </p>
          <p>
   <label>Correct choice number </label>
   <input type="number" name="correct_choice" />
     </p>
     <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
     </p>
      </form>
```

I think here is my problem:

```js
 if($choice != ''){
           if($correct_choice == $choice) {
               $is_correct = 1;
           } else {
               $is_correct = 0;
           }
```

Before to add "titlu" row and his values, there was filled with "$value", but i changed with "$choice"